# REST Assured extremely slow at the first GET/POST request

Tags: java, integration-testing, rest-assured

The first request in REST Assured spends more than 2 extra seconds every time, when I run tests.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.get;

class RestAssuredFirstRequestDuplicateTest {
    static void getMeter(String method, String url) {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        get(url);
        long totalTime = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000;
        System.out.println(String.format("Run %s to %s => %d ms", method, url, totalTime));
    }

    @Test
    void slowStart() {
        getMeter("First", "google.com");
        getMeter("Second", "google.com");

        getMeter("First", "httpbin.org");
        getMeter("Second", "httpbin.org");
    }
}
```

And after run the test I've got following

```
Run First to google.com => 3320 ms
Run Second to google.com => 26 ms
Run First to httpbin.org => 20 ms
Run Second to httpbin.org => 28 ms
```

I found that issue with my local environment but right now it looks like a problem with REST Assured.

JUnit 5, REST Assured 3.1.0

Source code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vrrs3qyjklxwnmc/restassuredissue.zip?dl=0

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure if it helps, but the first time you spin up a java web application, nothing is cached. After loading a page, it then gets set into the cache. This might explain your test results.

Comment: That was my first idea, but not in that case because I've tested with other URLs including google.com/httpbin.org/etc.

Comment: Have you run this test multiple times on the same server instance? If you run this test multiple times on the same instance, then I would rule out cache. Another problem may be that you are running this test instantly upon launch. This might also cause time delays. The code presented should not cause any delays. If you add a bit more to the situation, I may be able to make a better educated guess.

Comment: >Have you run this test multiple times on the same server instance? Yes, I did, with the same result - few extra seconds for first request (didn't matter to the same URL, or not). But it seems a good point, will check it again later

Comment: Update question to show more clear example of the issue